# Using array to count only letters in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

hi i am suppose to write a program which will do the following 
Prompt the user to enter a String of data
Using the charAt(index) method in the String class to access each character in the string
individually, produce a count of the number of word lengths
Count only letters (regardless of upper or lower case) and treat spaces, numbers and punctuation
as word separators.
Display the number of words and lengths for all non-zero lengths, and the total number of words

for example lets say a sentence like this  : Hello Stack Over Flow

2 4 letter words
1 5 letter words
1 6 letter words
5 total words

i have something like this :

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int [] wordCount = new int [50];
    int i = 0 ,charCount = 0 , j=0;
    int counter=0;

    System.out.println("Enter the phrase");
    String userInput =input.nextLine().toUpperCase();

    for ( i = 0;i < userInput.length(); i++){

        char charAt = userInput.charAt(i);
        if (charAt >= 'A' && charAt <= 'Z') {
            counter++;

        }
        else{
            if(i-j>1){
                counter++;
                j=1;
            }
            else{
                i=j;
            }
            wordCount[counter]++;
            counter=0;
        }
    }

    wordCount[counter]++;
    System.out.println(userInput.length());







}
```

}

which only count total number of word but from this point forward i am stuck

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

First, *Hello Stack Over Flow* is four words. Second, I would start with the negation of `a-zA-Z` as the pattern for split. Then I would sort the words by length. Next we could iterate the words starting from the second one checking for the same size and getting a count. Then display. Something like,

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the phrase");
String userInput = input.nextLine();
String[] arr = userInput.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");
Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1 == null) {
            if (o2 == null) { return 0; }
            return -1;
        } else if (o2 == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        int c = Integer.valueOf(o1.length()).compareTo(o2.length());
        if (c != 0) { return c; }
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});
System.out.printf("%s contains %d words.%n", Arrays.toString(arr),
        arr.length);
int len = arr[0].length();
int pos = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    while (i < arr.length && arr[i].length() == len) {
        i++;
    }
    System.out.printf("%d %d letter words%n", i - pos, len);
    if (i >= arr.length) { i = arr.length - 1; }
    len = arr[i].length();
    pos = i;
}
```

Example output (with your provided input)

```
Enter the phrase
Hello Stack Over Flow
[Flow, Over, Hello, Stack] contains 4 words.
2 4 letter words
2 5 letter words
```